# Unable to get bundle data from two different activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, bundle

I'm able to get data from each single activity but unable to get when calling from both activities at a time.

I have 3 activities

1.GoogleLogin
2.FacebookLogin
3.MainActivity

I have this in my GoogleLogin:

```
  @Override
  public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    // Reaching onConnected means we consider the user signed in.

    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
    Person currentUser = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
  //Create the bundle
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    //Add your data from getFactualResults method to bundle
    bundle.putString("Google", "Logged in using Google Account");
    bundle.putString("GoogleUsername",  currentUser.getDisplayName());
    //Add the bundle to the intent
    i.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(i);


    // Indicate that the sign in process is complete.
    mSignInProgress = STATE_DEFAULT;
  }
```

I have this in my FacebookLogin:

```
          if (session.isOpened()) {

          // make request to the /me API
          Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            // callback after Graph API response with user object
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
              if (user != null) {

              Intent i = new Intent(FBMainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                  //Create the bundle
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    //Add your data from getFactualResults method to bundle
                    bundle.putString("Facebook", "Logged in using Facebook Account");
                    bundle.putString("LastName", user.getLastName());
                    bundle.putString("FirstName", user.getFirstName());
                    //Add the bundle to the intent
                    i.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(i);
              }
            }
          }).executeAsync();
        }
```

In My MainActivity I get them as shown:

```
       // 1. get passed intent 
       Intent facebookintent = getIntent();

       // 2. get message value from intent
       String lastName = facebookintent.getStringExtra("LastName");
       String firstName = facebookintent.getStringExtra("FirstName");

       // 3. get bundle from intent
       Bundle facebookbundle = facebookintent.getExtras();

       // 4. get status value from bundle
       String facebookstatus = facebookbundle.getString("Facebook");



       // 1. get passed intent 
       Intent googleintent = getIntent();

       // 2. get message value from intent
       String userName = googleintent.getStringExtra("GoogleUsername");

       // 3. get bundle from intent
       Bundle googlebundle = facebookintent.getExtras();

       // 4. get status value from bundle
       String googlestatus = googlebundle.getString("Google");

       if (facebookstatus=="Logged in using Facebook Account"){ 

           // 3. show message on textView 
           ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtUser)).setText("Hello" + " " + lastName + " " + firstName);

       }else if (googlestatus=="Logged in using Google Account"){ 

           // 3. show message on textView 
           ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtUser)).setText("Hello" + " " + userName);
       }
```

I'm unable to get GoogleUsername but able to get them individually when able to call from each single activity.

Comment: what you want to do? how you start one activity from two another activities as same time?

Comment: Actually I would like to check with which account user has logged in and get his username from his account

Comment: you need check your bundle that has witch key, `Facebook` or `Google`, after that get data from that, as you login with one of them, you need check that

Comment: Is that not what I have done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the logic flow, your activity can get started by either `facebook` or `google` login.
so you have to check and use it appropiately. do something like this

```
  // 1. get passed intent 
   Intent intent = getIntent();

   if (intent.getStringExtra("Facebook") != null){

     // 2. get message value from intent
     String lastName = intent.getStringExtra("LastName");
     String firstName = intent.getStringExtra("FirstName");

     if(intent.getStringExtra("Facebook").equals("Logged in using Facebook Account")){
       ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtUser)).setText("Hello" + " " + lastName + " " + firstName);
     }
 }else if(intent.getStringExtra("Google") != null){ 


     // 2. get message value from intent
     String userName = googleintent.getStringExtra("GoogleUsername");

     // 3. get bundle from intent
     Bundle googlebundle = facebookintent.getExtras();

     if(intent.getStringExtra("Google").equals("Logged in using Google Account")){
      ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtUser)).setText("Hello" + " " + userName);
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need check before check googleStatus and facebookStatus. ( in java we dont compare two String with `==` , compare that with `.equals()` method )

you need check that in your bundle google account is exists or facebook account, for that you need following code:

```
 if (bundle != null)
 {

     if ( bundle.containsKey("Facebook") )
     {    
       // user logged in with facebook account
     } 
     else if (bundle.containsKey("Google") )
     {
       // check google account
     }

}
```